# Connecting to a SFTP server via SOCKS5 proxy from a java client (code) without proxy authentication

Tags: java, proxy, sftp, socks, j2ssh

I am trying to connect to a SFTP server via socks5 proxy server from a standalone sftpclient, I am doing that using maverick-all library. My code works fine. Below is the code snippet :

```
private SshClient getSSHClient() throws Exception {
    SshClient ssh = null;
    SshClient forwardedConnection = null;
    /**
     * Create an SshConnector instance
     */
    SshConnector con = SshConnector.getInstance();
    Ssh2Context context = (Ssh2Context) con.getContext(SshConnector.SSH2);
    setupContext(context);
    context.setHostKeyVerification(new ConsoleKnownHostsKeyVerification());
    SocketTransport t = new SocketTransport(hostname, port);
    t.setTcpNoDelay(true);
    //System.out.println("t.isConnected() ->" + t.isConnected());
    ssh = con.connect(t, username, true);

    PasswordAuthentication pwd = new PasswordAuthentication();
    pwd.setPassword(password);
    ssh.authenticate(pwd);


    if (ssh.isAuthenticated()) {    
        System.out.println("authenticated");
        // Connect via socks5 proxy
        SshTransport spt = SocksProxyTransport.connectViaSocks5Proxy(hostname, port, proxyServerHost, proxyServerPort, proxyServerUsername,proxyServerPassword);

        forwardedConnection = con.connect(spt, username);
        PasswordAuthentication pwd2 = new PasswordAuthentication();
        pwd2.setPassword(password);
        forwardedConnection.authenticate(pwd2);
    }
    return forwardedConnection;
}
```

I now want to do it without using proxy authentication i.e without using proxy username and password as the proxy server (CCproxy) allows such configuration. I looked into the library code it is possible if we specify the method as '0'. Code can be found in github, below is the URL

https://github.com/sshtools/j2ssh-maverick/blob/master/j2ssh-maverick/src/main/java/com/sshtools/net/SocksProxyTransport.java

connectViaSocks5Proxy method.

line 204.

So is there any way to specify the authentication method ?